# Will Postgres automatically cache "active" records from a large table?

Tags: postgresql, caching, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-performance

I have a table which contains a large number of records but only a portion of them are "active" at any one time and my web app just needs to reference those. I have an updating process that runs each night which adds new (active) records and may re-activate older records.

Will postgres be able to figure out that it should cache the active records? If not, should I move the active records to a new table to help it -- or is there some other way of giving it a "hint"?

UPDATE - The active records are indicated by having a NULL value in a datetime field called end_date

Thanks

Comment: Could really do with more information on how these records are "active" or not.

Answer (score 2):

The operating system will cache active and recently used disk blocks. PostgreSQL relies mainly on the operating system disk cache. However, its own `shared_buffers` will cache hot pages too.

It sounds like this is a very roundabout way of saying "I have these queries I think are slower than they should be". Consider a read of http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "active record", might be a postgres terminology I just miss. If you simply mean a row named "active", lay an index on it. That way postgres can directly access them without rowwise search, so in a way it´s like a cache (rebuildt every time you alter a row)